# Which option is more optimal for exporting components?

Tags: reactjs, antd

When writing components on my own, I usually use names like :

```js
<Menu>
  <MenuItem/>
  <MenuItem/>
</Menu>
```

Now we have to work with the AntDesign library and they have the same menu made as follows :

```js
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item/>
  <Menu.Item/>
</Menu>
```

This approach is used simply to show that MenuItem cannot be used outside the Menu? Or are there any other reasons why they might have chosen this approach?

Comment: It's a compound component. I use this design pattern mostly to export a single component, e.g. `Menu`, and the consuming component has a single import, but can use ***all*** the components "attached" to `Menu`. Many times these compound components may work together and have *some* shared common state or context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Menu component declaration in Ant Design looks like this:

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component<MenuProps, {}> {
    static Divider: React.FC<import("rc-menu/lib/Divider").DividerProps>;
    static Item: typeof Item;
    static SubMenu: typeof SubMenu;
    static ItemGroup: typeof ItemGroup;
    render(): JSX.Element;
}
```

So it's a class and it has some static members that one of them is Item which is typeof Item that is an alias for MenuItem class as you can see below:

```
export default class MenuItem extends React.Component<MenuItemProps> {
    static isMenuItem: boolean;
    renderItemChildren(inlineCollapsed: boolean): {} | null | undefined;
    renderItem: ({ siderCollapsed }: SiderContextProps) => JSX.Element;
    render(): JSX.Element;
}
```

It means these are the types you are allowed to use in your Antd Menu component and it helps them not having inconsistency issues and stuff like that while developing Antd, therefore, they are using some kind of architecture and SOLID principles to help their written code being clean and maintainable.

To understand it better, I suggest you read some articles or a book about Design Patterns in JavaScript or TypeScript.

*Some of the most popular design patterns in React are compound components, higher-order components (HoC), and render props.*

**As for Menu component it seems to use compound design pattern** that you can read more about it here at the following link:

[https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-react-compound-components-9c4b3eb482e9/#:~:text=Compound%20components%20is%20a%20pattern,each%20other%20in%20the%20background](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-react-compound-components-9c4b3eb482e9/#:%7E:text=Compound%20components%20is%20a%20pattern,each%20other%20in%20the%20background).

Comment: How I understand, is it something like BEM aproach? When we'll have .menu and .menu__item ?

Comment: I just updated the answer, you can read more about it through the link I just inserted.